# Json data not showing in vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I am making a vue app. I put a .json file in static directory. I am trying to read it in the default HelloWorld.vue file. But it's not showing in the browser. Here is what it shows in the browser:

[image]

My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Successfully retrieved all registered applications",
    "Applications": [
        {
            "ApplicationID": "74382DOD",
            "ApplicationName": "OIMInstance2",
            "ApplicationType": "OIM",
            "APIToken": "ZM8R4FRiZWWKbl235u06zbArCdOBPlEKhqHQO8Y9RJ2HgBPC+cZgbIli8fFuNZaey/2tJciJuILIWIn24WTjGA=="
        },
        {
            "ApplicationID": "943ODA6G",
            "ApplicationName": "LDAPInstance2",
            "ApplicationType": "LDAP",
            "APIToken": "R9lDEW5dnN6TZg2sefEEzS6LWMNmFh4iLHMu47LmAsusHl0bZuh2rktSlXqSZRdHHEWq7sP4Xsdy6xNtDYE8xw=="
        }
    ]
}
```

My code in HelloWorld.vue is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>APPLICATION REGISTRATION</h1>
    <div v-for="udata in userData">
      Id : {{ udata.ApplicationID }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',

  data () {
    return {
      userData: []
    }
  },

   created: function() {
    axios.get('../../static/mockdata.json')
    .then(response => {
      this.userData = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      //this.errors.push(e)
    })
   }
}
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? How do I show the json data in the browser?

Comment: Why are you using axios  if you could only import the file?
 considering it is going through the loop the problem is the data returned and how you are making a reference.. Prob the attribute is returning undefined.

Comment: just try to console userData in callback of axios. data is comming in a proper way or not

Comment: if data comes in proper way in axios you can try that axios call in beforeMount() method or in mounted() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through **applications** object.Hence in order to get applicationId you will need to set data accordingly by only adding applications data in your **userData** variable.

Do as below.

```
 this.userData = response.data.Applications
```